# SmartConfig stopped working after upgrade to Xcode 12.5

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, esp32

My iOS app that is using the ESPTouch framework does no longer work - it compiles without errors, but the SmartConfig does not seem to reach the ESP32 anymore. The iOS version is 14.6. I am using IONIC 5 with Angular for development.

Anyone facing the same issues? Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Thank you.

V

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution on GitHub: https://github.com/EspressifApp/EsptouchForIOS/issues/59

Needed to include `[self._esptouchTask setPackageBroadcast:true];` Swift Programmers should call `task.setPackageBroadcast(true)`.